# How do I enable a button while it's in delay

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I want to enable a button the moment someone flips the switch.
Here's what I have so far:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    int num = 1;
    String pre = "";
    Date currentTime = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        changeTextViewToDate();

    }

    private void changeTextViewToDate() {

        Button steve = findViewById(R.id.nicememe);
        final TextView job = findViewById(R.id.MainDisplay);
        steve.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Switch simpleSwitch = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.emergency);
                Boolean switchState = simpleSwitch.isChecked();
                if (switchState == false) {
                    {
                        ((Button) findViewById(R.id.nicememe)).setEnabled(false);

                        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                ((Button) findViewById(R.id.nicememe)).setEnabled(true);

                            }
                        }, 3000);
                    }
                    job.setText(pre + Integer.toString(num) + " " + Calendar.getInstance().getTime() + System.getProperty("line.separator"));
                    job.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
                    num++;
                    String now = job.getText().toString();
                    pre = now;
                }
                else {
                    ((Button) findViewById(R.id.nicememe)).setEnabled(true);
                    job.setText(pre + Integer.toString(num) + " " + Calendar.getInstance().getTime() + " EMERGENCY" + System.getProperty("line.separator"));
                    job.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
                    num++;
                    String now = job.getText().toString();
                    pre = now;
                }

            }
        });
    }
}
```

What's happening is the button is getting disabled but when I flip the switch it's still disabled. Only if the switch is on can I press the button very quickly. I want it so even if it's in delay if the person switches on emergency that it enables the button to be pressed again. Is this possible?

Comment: `pre = now; now = pre;` what do you think this is doing?

Comment: puts now into pre, then puts pre into now. Since now has pre in it I think it adds another line into the existing now.

Comment: The onClick event will not be triggered while the button is disabled. You're disabling `R.id.nicememe` inside of the `R.id.nicememe` onClick function

Answer (score 0):

this is not the correct way of doing UI operations from another thread. Call runOnUiThread whenever you do UI operation from another thread. Like this :

```
 new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                          MainActivity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                   @Override
                                   public void run() {                                     
                              ((Button)findViewById(R.id.nicememe)).setEnabled(true);
                                    }
                                  });  
                              }
                    }, 3000);
```